# sed replace regex correct syntax

Tags: sed

`<div data-name="abc" data-location="abcd"><div>Something</div></div>`

```
sed 's/data-name="*"/data-name="helloworld"/g'
```

I am trying to replace `data-name="abc"` `abc` to `helloworld`

However, my result returns

`data-name="helloworld"helloworld"abc"`

I am expecting to be `data-name="helloworld"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` matches zero or more *preeceding* character. So `"*` matches zero or more `"` characters. So `data-name="*"` matched `data-name="` (the `"*` matched zero characters) and substituted that.

You seem want to actually match the text inside `"`. So match everything up until a `"`.

```
sed 's/data-name="[^"]*"/data-name="helloworld"/g'
```

Note that [you can't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and it's better to use xml aware tools to edit html. It's fun to learn regexes with regex crosswords.

Answer (score 0):

Though html files should be parsed by a html proper parser since OP is already going with tools `sed` so adding this solution with `awk`.

```
awk -v str="helloworld" '
match($0,/"[^"]*/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART) str substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(^[^"]*\)\("[^"]*"\)\(.*\)/\1"helloworld"\3/' Input_file
```

In case you want to look for line which has `data-name` string then could change `match($0,/"[^"]*/){` line to `/data-name/ && match($0,/"[^"]*/){` AND `s/` to `/data-name/s` in above solutions.